# Jenkins Job access inside subfolder

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, controlled-folder-access

My folder structure is like this - folder1/subfolder1A/job1A. I want to give permission to Jenkins user to only job1A and restrict other, how can I achieve this.

I tried to write pattern (in Item roles) like this = folder1/subfolder1A/job1A (not working)  or folder1/(subfolder1A.*)/job1A (not working)

And many more...

If anyone has a solution, please share.